# How can I get my two VM's in virtual box to ping each other?

Tags: virtual-machine

Although each of the adapters are set to "internal network", I keep getting, network is unreachable.. Help Please .. Please make it simple

Comment: Which virtualization software you use?
What is the network configuration of both virtual machines?

Comment: And which OS are you on?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your swift response.. I'm using Oracle Virtual box , both machines, under the NETWORK, both have intel pro/1000 MT "Internal Network" as the choice of network, i presume this to allow them ping each other .. Both Os are Red hat (64bit)

Comment: You keep getting "network is unreachable" in response to *what* command? What host OS are you using? How are your network interfaces configured in the host? Is there a DHCP server or are you configuring the hosts manually?

Answer (score 0):

```
* Internal networking.This mode is much like bridged networking when it comes to communicating with the other virtual
machines on the same host, but it is more secure and does not let you communicate with an external network.
```

In this network mode the guests can communicate *ONLY IF* you have configured the network interface on the guests with a proper address-scheme.

A couple of hints: IPv4, Static/Dynamic IP, Gateway IP, Netmask ?

```
win: ipconfig /all linux: if addr show
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no DHCP server when using internal networking.  Have you configured static IP addresses on both VM's?